# Como organizar aspas de conteúdo HTML e PHP dentro do echo?

Tags: php, html

Caros Colegas,
estou enfrentado uma certa dificuldade ao incluir um determinado conteúdo dentro de um echo, por exemplo:

Possuo essa estrutura condicional:

```
if ($row_usuario['id_relacionado'] != 0) {


    echo = " ";


}else{

echo = "Não existe arquivo relacionado";

}
```

Preciso inserir a seguinte DIV dentro do echo do IF:

```html
<div id="id_resultado"><a href="visualizar.php?id=<?php echo $row_usuario['id_relacionado']?>"><?php echo $idrelacionado['numero']?></a></div>
```

Pelo seguinte motivo, gostaria que somente se existir o id aparecera a palavra lincada.

Alguém poderia me dar uma força?

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem, seria isso?

```
if ($row_usuario['id_relacionado'] != 0) {
 echo "
    <div id='id_resultado'><a href='visualizar.php?id=". $row_usuario['id_relacionado'] ."'>". $idrelacionado['numero'] ."</a></div>";
} else{
echo "Não existe arquivo relacionado";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sempre quando for colocar `HTML` dentro de um `echo`, lembre-se de organizar as aspas! Se abrir um echo com aspas duplas `"` os atributos do `HTML` devem ser abertos com aspas simples `'`, e assim sucessivamente.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
if ($row_usuario['id_relacionado'] != 0) {


    echo = "<div id='id_resultado'><a href='visualizar.php?id=" .$row_usuario['id_relacionado'] .">" . $idrelacionado['numero'] ."</a></div>";


}else{

echo = "Não existe arquivo relacionado";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado pelas respostas caro Daniel e Sampaio Leal, me ajudou muito, realmente estava fazendo algumas confusões no que se refere as aspas, mas também na parte de concatenar, transformando isso:

```
<?php echo $row_usuario['id_relacionado']?>
```

para isso:

```
. $row_usuario['id_relacionado'] .
```

Esta foi a estrutura que apliquei e funcionou:

```
if ($row_usuario['id_relacionado'] != 0) {


    echo "<div id='id_resultado'><a href='visualizar.php?id=". $row_usuario['id_relacionado'] ."'>". $idrelacionado['numero'] ."</a></div>";


}else{

    echo "Não existe arquivo relacionado.";

}
```

Quando inseri o echo com sinal de = estava me retornando o seguinte erro:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Fiz a remoção e tudo voltou a funcionar, mesmo o problema já estando resolvido alguém poderia me explicar essa diferença de utilizar o echo com ou sem sinal de igual?

Muito obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Bom que funcionou. Nunca vi echo com =, é sinal de atribuição tipo em "$var = x". O echo é seguido direto pelo que será "echoado" entre aspas. Não esqueça de aceitar a resposta para ajudar outros usuários. Boa sorte aí.